# Using csvreader against a gzipped file in Python

Tags: python, csv, gzip

I have a bunch of gzipped CSV files that I'd like to open for inspection using Python's built in CSV reader.  I'd like to do this without having first to manually unzip them to disk.  I guess I want to somehow get a stream to the uncompressed data, and pass this into the CSV reader.  Is this possible in Python?

Comment: In addition to the native Python solutions here, `pandas` package has [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) reader with gzip support

Comment: Just to add, in pandas this is done by adding compression="gzip" as parameter to read_csv

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `gzip` module:

```
with gzip.open(filename, mode='rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #...
```

Comment: If `filename='tzaman.csv'` then its makes file `tzaman.csv` which is an archive file, and contains another file `tzaman.csv` which is actually a csv file. if we name it as `abc.zip` then its adds `abc.zip` which is a zip and contains a file `abc.zip` which actually is a csv. What to do?

Comment: Does it not compress the file?

Comment: It does not create an archive. Gzip is only a stream compressor. The filename should be called 'tzsman.csv.gz' to help identify the file type. Also, the gzip library does not support the with statement in Python 2.6.8.

Comment: @Doug: you can decorate a non-context-manager object with [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) with dummy `__enter__/__exit__()` methods, but it's better to do the real thing

Comment: @smci thanks for the tip. Fast forward 3 1/2 years, I am using Python 3.6 exclusively, unless I have to access an old API like yum. The contextlib does provide some slick decorators.

Comment: this fails, newline character is not preperly interpreted when reading binary files, and gzip opens the files in binary mode

Comment: @mazs you can specify file mode in the `gzip.open` call.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (using Python 3.7). It's getting `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)` error.

Comment: @Devy as already mentioned above, you can specify the mode in the `open` call. I've edited the answer to open in text mode which should fix the error.

Answer (score 30):

I've tried the above version for writing and reading and it didn't work in Python 3.3 due to "bytes" error. However, after some trial and error I could get the following to work. Maybe it also helps others:

```
import csv
import gzip
import io


with gzip.open("test.gz", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(io.TextIOWrapper(file, newline="", write_through=True))
    writer.writerow([1, 2, 3])
    writer.writerow([4, 5, 6])

with gzip.open("test.gz", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(file, newline=""))
    print(list(reader))
```

As amohr suggests, the following works as well:

```
import gzip, csv

with gzip.open("test.gz", "wt", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([1, 2, 3])
    writer.writerow([4, 5, 6])

with gzip.open("test.gz", "rt", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    print(list(reader))
```

Comment: This solution also works with the `io.BufferedReader` which might be faster according to some [benchmarks](http://ebnj.net/pythongzipbenchmarks/). Simply wrap `gzip.open` with `io.BufferedReader` making it `with io.BufferedReader(gzip.open("test.gz", 'r')) as file:`

Comment: you can skip TextIOWrapper/BufferedReader if you use gzip.open( mode='rt'

Comment: This is useful. I am just running into one issue though. what i have is tsv file gzipped. that is tab-separated file, rather than comma-separated file. How do I convert the tabs to commas?

Comment: You probably can use that `csv.reader` has a lot of options to customize the format https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params

Answer (score 7):

a more complete solution:

```
import csv, gzip
class GZipCSVReader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.gzfile = gzip.open(filename)
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(self.gzfile)
    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next()
    def close(self):
        self.gzfile.close()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.reader.__iter__()
```

now you can use it like this:

```
r = GZipCSVReader('my.csv')
for map in r:
    for k,v in map:
        print k,v
r.close()
```

EDIT: following the below comment, how about a simpler approach:

```
def gzipped_csv(filename):
    with gzip.open(filename) as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in r:
            yield row
```

which let's you then

```
for row in gzipped_csv(filename):
    for k, v in row:
        print(k, v)
```

Comment: Neat. Neater if you can add `__enter_/__exit__()` context-manager methods so it can be used with `with` statement.