# why `write_through=True` is necessary when write a zipped csv?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

[Using csvreader against a gzipped file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252812/using-csvreader-against-a-gzipped-file-in-python)

```
with gzip.open('test2.csv.gz', 'w') as f:
    #csv_w = csv.writer(io.TextIOWrapper(f, write_through=False)) # write empty csv.gz file
    csv_w = csv.writer(io.TextIOWrapper(f, write_through=True)) # ok
    csv_w.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    csv_w.writerow([1,2,3])
    csv_w.writerow([4,5,6])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

> If write_through is True, calls to write() are guaranteed not to be
>   buffered: any data written on the TextIOWrapper object is immediately
>   handled to its underlying binary buffer.

Question> I want to buffered write and set `write_through=False`. However, it will generate empty csv.gz file. But, it works if I switch to `write_through=True`.

Any reason why only `write_through=True` is supported here?

Python version: 3.5

Answer (score 0):

In order to compact the file, GZ has to find patterns in the file. The compression formula used by GZ analyses the file in question, if it doesn't exist, it outputs nothing from what I can tell. You can read more about how DEFLATE works [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)

Setting the "write_through" flag to True, it flushes the buffer to disk, from there GZ can read it.  If you don't, then the CSV writer keeps the information in a local buffer that's not accessible to gzip.

I hope that helps.

If you want to write to a file directly, you can do the following, removing the need for the `io` buffer.

```
gzip.open('test2.csv.gz', 'wt', newline='') as f: 
  csv_w = csv.writer(f) # ok
```

Comment: `csv_w = csv.writer(f)` doesn't work either. I assume this is related to python 3.

Comment: I know it expects the file to be opened with newline='' parameter set - you can check https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.  Try adding it to the gzip.open statement? I'm not on a Python machine right now so I can't test, but I'm pretty curious.

Comment: This works  

with gzip.open('test2.csv.gz', 'wt', newline='') as f:
    csv_w = csv.writer(f) # ok

Basically, writing in text, which adds an automatic newline character. That flushes the buffer automatically if memory serves me right.