# Reading csv.gz file in torchtext

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchtext

Pandas’s read_csv works for csv.gz as well.

Is there a way to achieve similar with PyTorch?https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Dataset doesn’t seem to have such an option.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: No, this is not supported by TabularDataset**

[torchtext.data.TabularDataset](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#tabulardataset) uses [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

[Using csvreader against a gzipped file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252812/using-csvreader-against-a-gzipped-file-in-python) suggests if you open the file with `gzip.open`, csv.reader can read it.

However, TabularDataset asks for a file path, not a file pointer, so digging into the [source code](https://pytorch.org/text/_modules/torchtext/data/dataset.html), it uses

```
io.open(os.path.expanduser(path), encoding="utf8")
```

To open the filepath. Since .gz is not utf8, this won't read the file correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation! Seems there isn't a way to pass a file object to it. Any similar functions in torch you may that work?

Comment: You could just copy the source code of TabularDataset and replace the file open line.